# Django 'FloatField' is not callable

Tags: django, django-models, pycharm

I keep getting these annoying highlights in my model field declarations [image: Problem Screenshot]

When I hover mouse over it, it says 'FloatField' is no callable. This is happening for all field types except for CharField. The project runs fine and I'm able to migrate the model to DB but these highlights are annoying. How can I get rid of them? Please advise.

```
from django.db import models

class ProjectModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    discipline_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    demo_field = models.FloatField(verbose_name='flow(kg/s)', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: What text editor are you using?

Comment: Pycharm Community Edition

Comment: you should configure the python interpreter in PyCharm (virtualenv, docker, ...) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html